# Setting Heroku DATABASE_URL to Pyramid Config

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Goal: Set the Heroku `DATABASE_URL` variable to `sqlalchemy.url=postgres://...` settings in `__init__.py` and `development.ini` file. Currently, I am connecting directly to the database address (which can change).

Issue as reported by Heroku support:

> If you have hard coded the database connection string into your ini
>   file that is probably not the best idea. While it will work for now,
>   if sometime in the future we need to change where you database is
>   running (which does happen for various reasons) then your application
>   will no longer connect to your database. If your database does move,
>   we do keep the DATABASE_URL updated so your application should use
>   this. Maybe change `sqlalchemy.url` to `sqlalchemy.url = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')` if this is not what it is already set to.

However, the address `sqlalchemy.url = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')` does **NOT** work. It crashes my app. I have even attempted: `sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')`, `sqlalchemy.url = postgres://os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')`, and finally `sqlalchemy.url = postgres://'DATABASE_URL'`. All of which do **NOT** work.

SQLALCEHMY `engine_config` setup: [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine_from_config)

> 

```
sqlalchemy.engine_from_config(configuration, prefix='sqlalchemy.',
 **kwargs)
```

> Create a new Engine instance using a configuration dictionary.
>
> The dictionary is typically produced from a config file.
>
> The keys of interest to `engine_from_config()` should be prefixed, e.g.
>   sqlalchemy.url, sqlalchemy.echo, etc. The ‘prefix’ argument indicates
>   the prefix to be searched for. Each matching key (after the prefix is
>   stripped) is treated as though it were the corresponding keyword
>   argument to a `create_engine()` call.
>
> The only required key is (assuming the default prefix) `sqlalchemy.url`,
>   which provides the database URL.
>
> A select set of keyword arguments will be “coerced” to their expected
>   type based on string values. The set of arguments is extensible
>   per-dialect using the engine_config_types accessor.
>
> Parameters:    configuration – A dictionary (typically produced from a
>   config file, but this is not a requirement). Items whose keys start
>   with the value of ‘prefix’ will have that prefix stripped, and will
>   then be passed to `create_engine`. prefix – Prefix to match and then
>   strip from keys in ‘configuration’. kwargs – Each keyword argument to
>   `engine_from_config()` itself overrides the corresponding item taken
>   from the ‘configuration’ dictionary. Keyword arguments should not be
>   prefixed.

## Outside Example (doesn't work for me):

I believe the issue is with the way settings and engine are setup in my app. I found this tutorial helpful, but my code is different: [Environment Variables in Pyramid](http://codefellows.github.io/python-dev-accelerator/lectures/pyramid_day4.html#environment-variables-in-pyramid)

> What we ultimately want to do is dynamically set the sqlalchemy.url to
>   the value of our DATABASE_URL environment variable.
>   learning_journal/**init**.py is where our .ini file’s configuration
>   gets bound to our Pyramid app. Before the current settings get added
>   to the Configurator, we can use os.environ to bring in our
>   environment’s DATABASE_URL.

```
# __init__.py

import os

from pyramid.config import Configurator


def main(global_config, **settings):
        """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application.
        """
        settings["sqlalchemy.url"] = os.environ["DATABASE_URL"]
        config = Configurator(settings=settings)
        config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
        config.include('.models')
        config.include('.routes')
        config.scan()
        return config.make_wsgi_app()
Because we should always try to keep code DRY (and prevent future confusion), remove the sqlalchemy.url keyword from development.ini.
```

## MY CODE:

## **init**.py

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application"""
    #global_config argument is a dictionary of key/value pairs mentioned in the [DEFAULT] section of an development.ini file
    # **settings argument collects another set of arbitrary key/value pairs
    #The main function first creates a SQLAlchemy database engine using sqlalchemy.engine_from_config() from the sqlalchemy. prefixed settings in the development.ini file's [app:main] section. This will be a URI (something like sqlite://):
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    Session.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    ...
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')
    config.include('pyramid_mailer')
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static', cache_max_age=3600)
```

## development.ini

```
#former db:
#sqlalchemy.url = postgres://localhost/NOTSSdb

#works, but unstable should db move:
sqlalchemy.url = postgres://ijfbcvuyifb.....
```

## initialize_db script:

```
def main(argv=sys.argv):
    if len(argv) < 2:
        usage(argv)
    config_uri = argv[1]
    options = parse_vars(argv[2:])
    setup_logging(config_uri)
    settings = get_appsettings(config_uri, options=options)
    engine = engine_from_config(settings)
```

Comment: What do you mean by the database_url crashes your app?  Because the variable is not there or it's just not in that correct format you need and it crashes? If latter. I would just reformat  the string and pass it to your app.

Comment: @fatfantasma I have attempted multiple formats to no avail. What are you suggesting? I was directed to someone's config file here: https://gist.github.com/inklesspen/7442308 but i use `engine_from_config` and am uncertain how i would incorporate .get into settings.

Comment: Your init.py does not have the line         settings["sqlalchemy.url"] = os.environ["DATABASE_URL"] and you still have the database URL hardwired in your development.ini file. Take it out.

Comment: @fatfantasma i tried that and got an error saying the system could not parse the line. I'll post it below the original post. I also removed the URL in the development.ini file.

Comment: Was it a pyramid config error or a sqlalchemy error?

Comment: @fatfantasma added the traceback and included the script (`initialize_db`) that may be causing issue too.

Comment: It seems it's looking for the key 'url' and not 'sqlalchemy.url".

Comment: yeah.. i think i need to keep the `url` portion and somehow integrate that into the settings on both `__init__.py` and `initialize_db` because that is where the engine is created.

Comment: it works with just `'sqlalchemy.'` when connecting to a `url`.

Comment: There you go. You are just using the wrong key; )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125024/discussion-between-thesayhey-and-fat-fantasma).